# ASP.Net: Textbox change giving errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am trying to run a function when a user has finished entering text in the text-box field.

But when I try to compile the code I get this error

Error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.account_default_testingpage_aspx'
does not contain a definition for 'GetAverageRent_TextChanged' and no
extension method 'GetAverageRent_TextChanged' accepting a first
argument of type 'ASP.account_default_testingpage_aspx' could be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

any idea how to fix this?

My markup is

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="PostcodeTxb" runat="server" OnTextChanged="GetAverageRent_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true">EnterPostcode</asp:TextBox>
```

My c# is

```
private void GetAverageRent_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox PostcodeTxb = sender as TextBox;
   if (PostcodeTxb != null)
   {
       string theText = PostcodeTxb.Text;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your event handler is `private`.

If you're defining the event handler in the mark-up, it must be `protected` or `public`.  Normally you would use `protected`.

Change...

```
private void GetAverageRent_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

To...

```
protected void GetAverageRent_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

your textbox id and code-behind method is mismatched So your code is wrong,it may be like this:-

my markup is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="GetAverageRent" runat="server" OnTextChanged="GetAverageRent_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

C# code is

```
private void GetAverageRent_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox PostcodeTxb = sender as TextBox;
            if (PostcodeTxb != null)
            {
                string theText = PostcodeTxb.Text;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what did you change? i can only see ID in asp has changed, also it still give me the same error when i copied and pasted them in

Comment: It's always a good idea to state what the change you're suggesting is, rather than copying/pasting the entire thing and expecting people to find a tiny alteration

Comment: Still give me the same error even after i copied and pasted over

Comment: Sorry @Hardik, but the name of the control and the name of the event handler have absolutely nothing to do with each other. This answer is simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you've changed the textbox name from GetAverageRent to PostcodeTxb after adding the method.
Go to youraspfile.aspx.designer.cs where your TextBox PostcodeTxb defined and add GetAverageRent_TextChanged event. It is recommended to use the same controlname_eventname for the event of the control to avoid confusions. For example, your event name must be PostcodeTxb_TextChanged instead of GetAverageRent_TextChanged.

`PostcodeTxb.TextChanged +=new EventHandler(PostcodeTxb_TextChanged);`
has to be changed as 
`PostcodeTxb.TextChanged +=new EventHandler(GetAverageRent_TextChanged);`
if you want to keep the current naming.

Comment: As I said to Hardik in their answer, the name of the control and the name of the event handler have absolutely nothing to do with each other.  You are correct that it makes sense to keep them aligned to stop confusion, but the fact they are different makes absolutely no difference

Comment: Agreed. What I meant was this part  PostcodeTxb.TextChanged +=new EventHandler(PostcodeTxb_TextChanged);

Comment: Agreed. What I meant was this part  
PostcodeTxb.TextChanged +=new EventHandler(PostcodeTxb_TextChanged);
has to be changed as 
PostcodeTxb.TextChanged +=new EventHandler(GetAverageRent_TextChanged);
 Otherwise he'll get the error as the method is not defined.
It is good if he keep both name as same.